# AWS Golang S3 manager upload: Access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I am using S3 upload manager to upload a large file into S3.

```
if _, err := uploader.UploadWithContext(ctx, &s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket:          aws.String(s.Config.GetS3ExportBucket()),
        Key:             aws.String(key),
        Body:            bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()),
        ContentEncoding: aws.String("gzip"),
        ContentType:     aws.String("application/json"),
    }); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to upload file, %w", err)
    }
```

As per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuAndPermissions.html) AWS document I have provided the permissions as well to my lambda.

```
#Created Policy for IAM Role
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3_write_policy" {
  name        = "${local.namespace}-s3-write-access"
  description = "Allow Lambda to access s3 where back will be written"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_write_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_write_policy" {
  statement {
    sid       = "WriteObjectActions"
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = [
      "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
      "s3:PutObject",]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.db_export.arn]
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting access denied error from S3.

Comment: Without seeing the URL you are PUTing to and the resource string, it is impossible to see you are are correct. Replace sensitive parts and re-post with URL and Resource strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide access to not just the bucket but all the objects inside bucket as well.

Try this policy

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_write_policy" {
  statement {
    sid       = "WriteObjectActions"
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = [
      "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
      "s3:PutObject",]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.db_export.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.db_export.arn}/*"]
  }
}
```